# Offline time synchronisation in cascade

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have the following setup :

```
[Group1] :
- Server 1 (Linux)
- Client 1 (Windows)
- Client 2 (Windows)
  ...
- Client n (Windows)

[Group2] :
- Server 2 (Linux)
- Client 1 (Windows)
- Client 2 (Windows)
  ...
- Client n (Windows)
```

All computers in group 1 are on the same switch.
All computers in group 2 are on the same switch.

Sometimes, group 1 and group 2 are connected (with an ethernet cable between the two switches).
Sometiles, they are not.

When Group 1 and Group 2 are used separatly (they are disconnected) I want every computer in group 1 to be time-synchronized and every computer in group 2 to be time synchronized (I do not care if group 1 and group 2 do not share the same time).
When Group 1 and Group 2 are used together (they are connected), I want every computer (in group 1 and group 2) to be time-synchronized.

None of the computers will ever be on the Internet.
I absolutly do not care if they do not have the "right time" (if they think it is 5:47:33 when it's actually 4:22:17) all I want is that they share the same time (if it is 5:47:33 on one computer, then it must be 5:47:33 on every connected computers).

**What I managed to do this far :**

- Use server 1 as a NTP server. It uses its own system time and serves it on the network.
- Sync group 1's clients with the server (using nettime).

**What I tried :**

- Configure server 2 as a NTP server, using server 1 as primary source and its own system time as a secondary source.
  **Problem :** it doesn't work.
  And I get why : NTP is not made for that. If the two sources provides vastly different times, it has to figure out a way to "find the truth". In fact, NTP is way more complicated than what I need...

**What I'm considering :**

- Configure server 2's NTP server exactly like server 1's (ie telling it to use its own system time as a reference) and syncing server 2's system time on server 1's.
  **Problem :** I cannot find a way to tell ntpd to act as a server, and only as a server, and to use another client to sync the system time.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !